The problem of the ages of Judah's sons and grandson
‬

And it came to pass at that time, that Judah went down from his brethren, and turned in to a certain Adullamite, whose name was Hirah.
Genesis 38:1 (KJV)

Genesis 38:1 and the rest of the chapter tells us the story of Judah and his children. According to the account, after the sale of Joseph to the Midianites, Judah, possibly driven by remorse, moves away from his brothers and marries with a Canaanite. She later becomes pregnant, and bears him three children: Er, Onan and Shelah.
Judah then marries his firstborn, Er, to another woman, Tamar. However, Er dies early due to his cruelty towards his wife. According to the law of levirate, Onan then marries Tamar, but he also ends up dead, due to the practice of coitus interruptus, in order not to give descendants to his deceased brother. Judah asks Tamar to wait until Shelah is old enough to marry, and then some time passes.
Moving forward, Shelah marries another woman, Judah deceives Tamar. Tamar then deceives Judah, getting him pregnant with Perez and Zerah. When Israel leaves for Egypt, Perez is already a father, and Judah is therefore a grandfather, since his sons, Hezron and Hamul, is listed among those who left for Egypt:

And these are the names of the children of Israel, which came into Egypt, Jacob and his sons: Reuben, Jacob's firstborn. [...] And the sons of Judah; Er, and Onan, and Shelah, and Pharez, and Zarah: but Er and Onan died in the land of Canaan. And the sons of Pharez were Hezron and Hamul.
Genesis 46:8,12 (KJV)

The problem is that this all has to fit into just 22 years, which is the interval between Joseph's trip to Egypt and his revelation to his brothers (Joseph was 17 years old when he was sold, and thirty when he became governor. When he revealed himself to his brothers he was already in the second year of hunger, making him 39 years old. 39-17=22 years). Therefore, to reconcile all these facts, Er, Onan, Selah and Perez could not have been more than 10 years old when they got married and had children. And I don't need to explain much because this seems problematic.
"Well, perhaps Hezron and Hamul may not have been at the departure for Egypt, and were born later, the author just mentioned them without any chronological purpose." This was my initial thought, and it would be a good solution if not for Genesis 46:26, what says that the total number of Jacob's descendants who went down to Egypt was 66. Considering the list given in the previous verses, it is only possible to reach this number if we count the sons of Perez.
In the few attempts to solve this problem that I found (which were really very few, this seems to be a subject that is rarely discussed), the justification is almost always the same: that the age standards for marriage at the time were different, that boys entered puberty earlier, and there could still be some cultural factor. The Jewish tradition assigns all of these characters  ages to be 7 or 8 years old when they become parents, which sounds even more absurd to me, and the justifications seem to be very vague, and hardly credible. For comparison, Isaac was weaned at 5 years old according to the same Jewish tradition. Could he, just a mere 2 years later, already be getting married and having kids??
Jacob married at 84 years, Esau at 40, Isaac also at 40, Joseph at 30, Judah himself at 20 or more, and probably your brothers too. If you check the entire bible in fact, you will see that the generation age is almost always around 20/30 years old. The youngest father we know of in the Bible is King Josiah, who became a father at the age of 14. The youngest father in world history, that there is proof, was 11 years old. Some sources cite a supposed father of 9 years old in 1910, in China, but there is no proof that this actually occurred. Would Judah's sons and grandson be an exception in his entire family and in the all secular history, and even more a so extreme exception? And even if it were an exception, would it occur twice in a row? It doesn't seem very plausible to me.
The only way out would then be to consider that the story actually predates the sale of Joseph, but the beginning of the chapter leaves no room for that. So how to solve this problem?

This is easily resolved by showing that the underlying assumption of 22 years is not correct.
First, we should note that the material in Genesis is NOT all in Chronological order.  To plot things more accurately, note the material in the appendix below.  From this we can deduce the following:

Jacob in 71 years old when he moved to live with Laban in Padam Aram
Jacob returns from Padam Aram at age 91 (20 years later) with 11 of his 12 sons already born.  The oldest, Reuben is now 12 years old.  Judah would be a few years younger.  Joseph was born just as they arrived.
When Jacob returned from Padam Aram he first settled in Shechem (Gen 33:18), purchased some land and then built stalls for this cattle and flocks. Thus, he probably stayed in Shechem for a few years. Following the incident with Diah (Gen 34) Jacob moved to Bethel (Gen 35:1, 14, 15) and then moved to Ephrath (Gen 35:16, 17) where Benjamin was born.
Joseph was 17 years old and Jacob 108 when Joseph was sold into slavery.  Reuben was 30 and Judah a few years younger.  This was old enough to have started a family.
Joseph was 39 years old, and Jacob was 130 when they arrived in Egypt.  Reuben would have been 52 and Judah a few years younger.

People at 50 years of age are old enough to have grandchildren.  The incident in Gen 38 probably occurred before Joseph went to Egypt giving plenty of time for grandchildren.
APPENDIX - The Chronology of Isaac:

Isaac born to Abraham at the age of 100, Gen 21:5
Isaac marries Rebekah at age 40, Gen 25:20
Isaac becomes the father of Jacob at age 60, Gen 25:26
Jacob (at age 71) deceives Isaac when he is 131, Gen 47:9, 45:6, 41:47
Jacob returns from Padam Aram after 20 years at age 91, as Joseph is born,
Isaac 151. Gen 30:25.
Joseph is sold into slavery at age 17 (Gen 37:2), Jacob is 108, Isaac is 168.
Isaac dies at age 180, Gen 35:28.


Actually, Jacob's departure would only happen when he was 97 years old. If you proceed from Gen 30:25, when Joseph is born at the age of 91, you will see that he will still have another 6 years of work, when he accumulated the cattle. Gen 31:38-41 shows this more clearly, revealing that he spent 20 years with Laban (although some argue that the two 20-year quotes are two distinct periods, adding up to 40). In any case, none of this affects the age of Joseph, who is always born at Jacob's 91st birthday. Judah can be born, minimally, to Jacob's 88 or 68 years, being 20 or 40 years in Gen 38:1

But in any case, none of these ages really solves the problem, although of course, 40 is a more acceptable age to start a family. I am aware that Genesis is not always in chronological order, but Gen 38:1 seems to make it clear that these events almost immediately followed the sale of Joseph, or were, at least, simultaneous. As Judah is present in the episode of Joseph's sale, and is even the one who gives this idea, Gen 38 can only be after this episode, and we still have the same old problem.
